# Syntax highlight for Sass is not working in Vim

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, sass, vim-syntax-highlighting

I just downloaded a Vim plugin for Sass syntax highlight.

The instructions say:

> install details put it into syntax
>   directory and add sass filetype
>
> au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.sass
>   setfiletype sass
>
> in your filetype.vim

I already placed **sass.vim** in `vimfiles/syntax/` (using windows).

And created a **filetype.vim file** with the code above (**au! Buf...**) in all the following directories:

- vimfiles/
- vimfiles/ftdetect
- vimfiles/ftplugins

but no one worked (I even typed the au! Buf... code in my vimrc).

My **.sass** files still looking like this:

[alt text http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/4791/sassi.png](http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/4791/sassi.png)

any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1433, and it worked. Thanks anyways! By the way, are you using haml?

Comment: Nope, just had recent troubles with syntax highlighting in vim.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know an easy fix, but try checking some vim settings with the following commands:

- Does enabling syntax explicitly fix your problem? `:syntax enable`
- Is filetype detection on? `:filetype`
- Does vim recognize this as a sass file? `:set filetype?`
- Check to make sure your script directories are in the runtime path `:set runtimepath?`
- Does manually loading the syntax file change anything? `:runtime! vimfiles/syntax/sass.vim`
- Also check if syntax highlighting works for other filetypes.

Comment: Additionally, it could also be the colorscheme itself, I had this issue and followed your steps to get closer to the solution myself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43919929/cannot-get-sass-indent-style-syntax-highlighting-to-work-in-vim-8?noredirect=1&lq=1