# cannot get SASS (indent style!) syntax highlighting to work in VIM 8

Tags: vim, sass, vim-plugin

#### VIM VERSION: VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled May  2 2017 03:55:34)

I'm using a number of [plugins](http://vimawesome.com/) with vim in order to make things work. I install them via the package manager [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim), my .vimrc can be found in my [dotfiles repository on github](https://github.com/SidOfc/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc)

Today, I tried to edit a SASS file with vim, however - the SASS file looks like a color-circus:

[image: vim broken sass highlighting]

I've followed some steps from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3089111/2224331) which include:

> 1. Does enabling syntax explicitly fix your problem? `:syntax enable`
> 2. Is filetype detection on? `:filetype`
> 3. Does vim recognize this as a sass file? `:set filetype?`
> 4. Check to make sure your script directories are in the runtime path `:set runtimepath?`
> 5. Does manually loading the syntax file change anything? `:runtime! vimfiles/syntax/sass.vim`
> 6. Also check if syntax highlighting works for other filetypes.

The answers to each point are:

1. Nothing changed, syntax remains exactly the same.
2. running `:filetype` returns `filetype detection:ON  plugin:ON  indent:ON`
3. running `:set filetype?` returns `filetype=sass`
4. running `:set runtimepath?` returns a long list of `~/.vim/bundle/[PATH]` entries of which none include `sass` in any form
5. running `:runtime! ~/.vim/bundle/vim-haml/syntax/sass.vim` also changes nothing
6. Syntax highlighting works for everything except SASS so far.

Additionally, I've tried adding some plugins from http://vimawesome.com/.
They all seem to be packages that either support a different package which should be supported by default or they do not support SASS (in addition to SCSS) highlighting.

This is, what I came up with in the end, still making no difference:

```
Plugin 'tpope/vim-haml'
Plugin 'JulesWang/css.vim'
Plugin 'hail2u/vim-css3-syntax'
```

The plugin `tpope/vim-haml` however, does have a [sass.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-haml/blob/master/syntax/sass.vim) file with it's syntax rules, it's actually the only up-to-date one compared to the rest which all seem to hang at "last updated 5+ years ago".

I basically have two questions, which I hope, more experienced vimologists will be able to answer, or point me in the right direction of fixing it myself:

- Is there any known *properly updated* SASS (indent syntax) plugin that I missed?
- If the above question is "no", then how could I get the `tpope/vim-haml` sass syntax file loaded for all my sass files?

I'm using SASS since, coming from Atom, it is less typing. I would prefer to keep the sass syntax if possible! (I am aware of conversion plugins but for the sake of my colleagues I would like to refrain from using any)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your SASS [looks fine](http://imgur.com/p7hHWsx) with the built-in support.

Comment: @romainl may I ask what exactly you did to achieve that? Or what specific version you are running (and perhaps OS if I may be so brutal) It was like this by default for me (pre-plugin install) but hasn't changed since, I'm going to just keep trying :)

Comment: It's just 8.0.596 without anything special done for SASS.

Comment: @romainl thank you very much, your hint helped me solve my issue without wasting another few hours (thumbsup!)

Answer (score 1):

## Answer

It was the colorscheme I was using, it caused severe formatting issues for my SASS files.

## TLDR;

I was using [roosta/srcery](http://vimawesome.com/plugin/srcery) and just tried an alternate colorscheme to test if the sass file would look more "sane", it now looks like this (using a random colorscheme):

[image: sane vim sass highlighting]

What we see here is still not perfect, but at least "sane" (I can understand why CSS3 `flex` properties aren't highlighted yet for instance), I'm simply going to try inform the author of the (really nice nonetheless) colorscheme to see if he is interested in improving it for SASS.

My lesson here, is that one should look at every aspect, I was thinking in the wrong direction and kept on going for too long as a result. When @romainl pointed out it looked fine using just regular-builtin-vim I started expecting a Plugin (a colorscheme) to be the suspect which solved my issue :)

Comment: If you want to emulate the screenshot posted by @romainl, try his own colorscheme https://github.com/romainl/Apprentice (also available as part of https://github.com/flazz/vim-colorschemes)